# Multiple servers generating error 500 in HANGFIRE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, hangfire

When I put the application into production with pod-managed Kubernetes architecture where it has the possibility of scaling so today it has two servers running the same application, hangfire recognizes both but returns an error 500

```
Unable to refresh the statistics: the server responded with 500 (error). Try reloading the page manually, or wait for automatic reload that will happen in a minute.
```

But when I leave on stage which is the testing application where there is only one server, hangfire works normally.

Hangfire Configuration:

```cs
Startup.cs

services.AddHangfire(x => x.UsePostgreSqlStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
   Authorization = new[] { new AuthorizationFilterHangfire() }
});           
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7w6s.png)

Comment: the 500 error comes from what URL? is it a controller action? or you are trying to view Hangfire dashboard?

Comment: Appears in dashboard, and I can't use jobs, 
I added an image with the error.

Comment: A this stage, this is more a kubernetes question than a hangfire one. Does something change if your change your prodution deployment to only one replica ?
What is the state of your pods ?
What do your pod's logs tell ? If not done, you will need to configure logging (a smart move for production) https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html

Comment: If I change production to just one replica, it works normally, I set the log, but where will they appear?

Comment: `kubectl logs your_pod_name -n your_pods_namespace`

Comment: My bet would be that application is stateful and you need to make sure user connects to the same instance every time. When connecting to website a request is sent to one instance and receives back a cookie and then your browser is sending next request which is goes to second instance and second instance sees the cookie and is thinking: "I don't know you" and sends you 500 error. Please check if that is the case

Comment: @HelloWorld


It may be a possibility. I did the following test: I started the application 2 times on localhost and pointed to the database on AWS, so HF recognized the 4 servers, 2 local and 2 that are on AWS, and ran normally, only the error happens when it runs on aws with kubertenes architecture with pods. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Run `kubectl port-forward pod/<pod_name> <local_port>:<container_port>` and then go to `localhost:<local_port>` in your browser. In this way you can be 100% sure you are hitting one specific instance of HF and check if error occurs. If its working fine then its highly probable the issue is as I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I found the following error: An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
When HF makes a post request.

Comment: I don't know that error. Forget about kubectl proxing and try setting session affinity (sticky session) on HF ingress object in k8s if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You can now add `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` to your service which should resolve this issue.

According to [this github post](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1248#issuecomment-517357213), the issue occured when you had multiple servers running the dashboard and due to load balancing when your request went to different server from the one you originally got the page, you'd see the error.

Adding `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true` to the dashboard should resolve the issue.

Excerpt Taken from [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1248#issuecomment-517357213)

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] {new HangfireAuthFilter()},
     IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true                                 // <--This
});
```

Comment: I recently ran into this problem in k8s as well, unfortunately I already have IgnoreAntiforgeryToken set to true and I am still seeing an anti forgery token exception in my logs.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by [persisting our DataProtectionKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in Redis for all replicas to read from.

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, $yourprefix::DataProtectionKeys");
```