# Hangfire Dashboard "Unable to refresh the statistics: the server responded with 500 (Internal Server Error). Try reloading the page manually .."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am getting this error on my hangfire dashboard on PPD server but working on my local and dev.

> Unable to refresh the statistics: the server responded with 500
> (Internal Server Error). Try reloading the page manually, or wait for
> automatic reload that will happen in a minute.

I am using asp.net core 3.0.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794486/1390548